# Django serve static files with user verification

Tags: django

I have a feature to implement - 'User can upload a zip file containing html, css and js which I will extract to a folder and later user can view it'. 
I could implement the feature by making 'location' rules in nginx proxy server, like if 'location' contains a keyword, say 'userhtml', then serve all the files from a particular dataroot location.
But, I want to add authentication to the system, if user is not logged in, he should not be able to see the files even if he know the url. That means all the requests(html,js,css) should pass through Django(can not be served directly by nginx). Can anyone give some pointers about how to do this.
- Thanks,

Comment: Since this is user uploaded content, I assume you mean "media files", not "static files".

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the answers.